# Type Mongo.Cursor is not generic

Tags: meteor, intellij-idea, typescript

I'm writing a meteor-angular2 application using intellij with typescript.

I created RoomInterface with the following code:

```
export interface RoomInterface {
  id:number;
  name:string;
}
```

then I have the following exported class:

```
export class Rooms extends MeteorComponent{
    rooms:Mongo.Cursor<RoomInterface>;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.subscribe('rooms',()=>{
            this.rooms=RoomsCollection.find();
        },true);
    }
}
```

the code runs fine but intellij is complaining with the error `type Mongo.Cursor is not generic` for `rooms:Mongo.Cursor<RoomInterface>;`

I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the definition for `Mongo.Cursor` in [this file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/08ed4e9f1869e37e29514d862e0158b40e550232/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts#L1125) is not generic:

```
 export interface Cursor extends Readable, NodeJS.EventEmitter {
```

If it was generic it would be something like:

```
 export interface Cursor<T> extends Readable, NodeJS.EventEmitter {
      // Use type T in a meaninful way e.g
      results: T[];
```

## Quick Fix

Change `rooms:Mongo.Cursor<RoomInterface>;` to `rooms:Mongo.Cursor;`